# Matlab using Interp1 for interpolation of matrx data set

Tags: matlab, interpolation, missing-data

I have a large data set of offline and online data, offline data is only taken every two hourly so wish to interpolate between the gaps. where the data is missing it is replaced with -9.999. I wish to interpolate in order to estimate these values. My idea is to find the missing values in the set to compare against the time intervals, but I cannot get it to work

This is what I have so far:

```
iv = 33; % column which holds cell weight
ind = find (Data(:,iv)<0);  % find the indices of missing values
Interp_iv = interp1 (Data(ind,2),Data(ind,2),Data(:,2),'spline')
```

Comment: The first and second parameters are the same. What does `data` contain? Can you provide more details on its structure?

Comment: Data is a 4750 x 49 numeric array, it has  online variables such as time, temperature, feed ect for multiple batches at varying time intervals (approx. every 0.2 hours)  it also has offline variables which are taken at every 2 hours this means in between the two hours I have the -9.990 aka not NaN (these are the values I want to replace with the interpolated numbers,

Answer (score 0):

Your x and v is the same try this:

```
interp1 (Data(ind,2),Data(ind,iv),Data(:,2),'spline')
```

Comment: This is the error message I keep getting: Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors must contain unique points.

Error in interp1 (line 161)
        F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);

Error in DataTreatment (line 10)
D = interp1 (Data(ind,2),Data(ind,iv),Data(:,2),'spline')